# Delayed Action?

Tags: mille-bornes

In the card game *Mille Bornes*, there is a point bonus for "Delayed Action":

> Additional bonus if trip is completed after all cards have been played from the draw pile (Delayed Action) ... 300

**If I draw the last card then complete my trip on the same turn, do I get this bonus?**

When this situation occurred in a recent game the other players argued the rule means the draw pile must be empty when the turn begins. I don't understand how it could mean that and would like a clear explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the rules,

> A hand ends when one side or the other completes a trip of exactly 1000 miles, or when the cards in the draw pile are exhausted. In the latter case, players must play out or discard in turn the the remaining cards in their hands.

It's clear to me you get the Delayed Action bonus if you enter "the latter case". However, the rules are quite ambiguous as to when "the latter case" is entered.

I don't have any reason to believe the player drawing the last card doesn't play out their turn normally, so I agree with your opponent. To me, the above means

> A hand ends when one side or the other completes a trip of exactly 1000 miles, or when the cards in the draw pile are exhausted. If there are no cards to draw, instead of taking turns as normal, players must play out or discard ...

The wording from the scoring summary you quoted even supports that. The bonus is only granted for a win "after the play", not "after the draw". This same wording is found earlier in the rules too.

In short, there's nothing special about the turn in which the last card is drawn. It's winning on one of the turns after (when running on fumes) that's dramatic and point worthy.

Comment: But there are still many cards which have not been played. If that's your interpretation then doesn't the win have to be the very last card?

Comment: No, not at all. I have no idea why you would think that.

Comment: So you can just wait until your next turn instead then. Especially if you know the other players can't win before then. Alrighty.

Comment: That's perfectly valid, yes. Keep in mind that even though your opponent might not be able to win, they could still play something that prevents you from moving.